# Btrfs errors on boot, can't boot my Fedora Linux

Tags: fedora, boot, btrfs

Hi Fedora 27 user here with btrfs partitioning on a ssd (default scheme choose at installation). All of a sudden my laptop can't boot, tried all kernel entries in GRUB. If I true the rescue we entry it says: "Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked."

The errors on the screen are:
bad tree block start
fail to open runtime journal (systemd)
error removing orphan entry, stopping orphan cleanup
pending csums is 16994304
remounting read-write after error is not allowed

Not sure what could it have trigger it, did a couple of cold reboots though recently (machine freezed). Many thanks for suggestions

PS please see attached screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkeSw.jpg)

Comment: Given you're getting an IO failure, have you tested the drive to make sure it's in good condition?

Comment: please how to do that?